# Third party cookies deprecation for provider-hosted SP online app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom, sharepoint-addin

We have a provider-hosted app that performs client-side calls (by using ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory). It seems that such calls are not working when third-party cookies are disabled on a browser. Chrome and other browsers are blocking third party cookies by next year. Of course users were able to un-block these cookies through the settings, but the sole fact that they had to do it caused some inconvenience specially for big organizations.

Is there any MS documentation regarding this or anyone has been able to figure out a way for moving forward?

Thanks,

Following this from google to disable third-party cookies, Im getting error loading RequestExecutor.js: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd

I have tried removing the IFrame that is being injected by SP Add in app so that the first party site and the provider-hosted app (Hosted somewhere outside the SP) are the same.